# IOerror when trying to serve file

Tags: python, apache, mod-wsgi, web.py

I'm trying to return a file of processed data to a webapp user using the web.py framework.  In this example the file is named plate3_v4.gb.  I'm trying to return it with the name results.gb.  This is based off of [this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/webpy/zep8cMeQtgk%5B1-25%5D).

Here's the code:

```
class ServeHandler():
    def GET(self):
        web.header("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=%s" %"results.gb")
        web.header("Content-Type", "gb")
        web.header('Transfer-Encoding','chunked')
        f = open('/usr/local/www/wsgi-scripts/uploads/plate3_v4.gb','rb')
        while 1:
            buf = f.read(1024 * 8)
            if not buf:
                break
            yield buf
```

When I go to the page that I think should serve the data to me I get

```
mod_wsgi (pid=21773): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/usr/local/www/wsgi-scripts/code.py'.
IOError: failed to write data
```

in my error log.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, a WSGI application should never set Transfer-Encoding response header itself. Only the underlying web server should do that. For mod_wsgi, Apache should do that automatically so long as no response content length provided.

As to the error, it indicates that the client closed the socket connection prior to it reading all the data which was returned.

Comment: Thanks for the info about Transfer Encoding, but is it really necessary not to set it? What if web.py app is used as stand alone app and mod_wsgi app? (I'm just wondering because this question is based on code that I posted in webpy group)

Comment: It is not your WSGI application which is formatting the response content in the required format. If you are doing that you are violating the WSGI specification, it is the underlying servers domain to worry about that. http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0333/#other-http-features

Comment: Thanks, then this cookbook entry http://webpy.org/cookbook/streaming_large_files is also incorrect, because it tells to set the chunked header.

Comment: Correct, that example is wrong and if it was run on a web server that didn't actually itself support chunked response content, the inclusion of the header would cause the client to fail. It would also fail either way if the client didn't support HTTP/1.1. In that case the web server would know client is not HTTP/1.1 and so not used chunked response, yet the WSGI application has overridden that and said it would be.